# word-puzzle vs. word-problem

Tags: discussion, tags

There are two clearly defined tags that have deceptively similar names — [word-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-puzzle) and [word-problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-problem).

A **word puzzle** is a puzzle involving words or wordplay.

A **word problem** is any *mathematical* puzzle expressed in words to give it the flavour of a story.

Some people have been using one for the other, and I'm wondering whether one of them should be renamed to something else.